# Change default mailbox search in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have selected the 'current mailbox' option from the search settings

[image: settings]

in the options tab in outlook but when searching emails it still defaults to 'all mailboxes'

I have also restarted outlook.
How do I change this?

Answer (score 1):

Your organization may have the default search scope specified via [group policy](https://getadmx.com/?Category=Office2016&Policy=outlk16.Office.Microsoft.Policies.Windows::L_SetDefaultSearchScope). Users will not be able to change the default once this policy is set, but they can manually change the scope while running a search.